# Php comparing muliple values in multidimensional arrays with another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

Simple example array

```
[0]=>array(2) {
["slug"]=>string(12) "exampleslug1"
["tax"]=>string(11) "exampletax1"}
[1]=>array(2) {
["slug"]=>string(12) "exampleslug2"
["tax"]=>string(11) "exampletax2"}
[2]=>array(2) {
["slug"]=>string(12) "exampleslug2"
["tax"]=>string(11) "exampletax3"}
```

Now i want to check another multidimensional array for both values.

So for example. I want to check if the slug is "exampleslug2" and the tax = "exampletax2"
So in this case it should return false/true/false.

Ive tried in_array but i can't seem to get that to work for multidimensional.
Can anyone help me out with a solution for checking multiple values in the multidimensional array to be the same as in a second multidimensional array.

If it try something like

```
if (!in_array($termSlug, $externalTermSlugs['slug']) && !in_array($termTax, $externalTermSlugs['tax']) ) {}
```

It adds everything multiple times, what i want to have is that it adds everything once unique and doesn't overwrite if it already exists.

Comment: Use a simple `foreach` iteration.

Comment: How about `in_array([ "slug" => $termSlug, "tax" => $termTax ], $externalTermSlugs)`? Also `array_unique($externalTermSlugs, SORT_REGULAR)` will deduplicate without any checks needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<?php
$arr = array( 0 => array("slug"=>"exampleslug1","tax"=>"exampletax1"),
             1 => array("slug"=>"exampleslug2","tax"=>"exampletax2"),
             2 => array("slug"=>"exampleslug2","tax"=>"exampletax3"));
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($value['slug']=="exampleslug2" && $value['tax']=="exampletax2"){
        echo "true"."<br>";
    }else{
        echo "false"."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if($value == ['slug'=>"exampleslug2",'tax'=>"exampletax2"]) {`

Comment: Thnx i ended up using something like your code. I'm doing a foreach to set the value if it exists, en then underneath if the value is not set to run my script ( i needed it to happen if the code didn't exist yet) 

    `foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
            if ($value === ['slug' => $termSlug, 'tax' => $termTax]) {
                $alreadySet = true;
                continue;
            }
        }`

Comment: instead of `thnx` accept the answer so every one can see this answer @tic